# Mockito and method access level

Tags: java, mockito

My question is connected with framework Mockito and methods, which can be tested.

Public methods can be well tested.

Private methods cannot be tested in Mockito, but they can be tested in other mocking frameworks.

What with protected methods and methods without access level (package-private)? As I checked, protected methods can be tested by creating inherited subclass with public method.
What is the best way of testing these methods?

Comment: Mockito is a mocking framework: it creates mocks, allow us to define comportement for them and to do verifications on those mocks. What do you mean by "can be tested"?

Comment: For example verify some methods or define returning parameter.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ (see limitations), for protected/default, those should usually not be mocked (too low level)

Comment: Where? I see only: "Can I mock private methods?" Nothing about rest.

Comment: It's implicit you can use protected/default on mock if and only if java allows you to call those methods from where you are

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the relationship to Mockito in this instance as if you're testing a method, you don't really want to mock that class.  To answer your question, there are a couple of options:

For package-private, I always create my test cases in the same package as the class under test so I can access them.

For package-private or protected methods, you can use reflection to change the access level, but that's definitely a headache.  What I would do is subclass and change the access level that way.

Comment: Reflection to change the access level? To much work and this kind of solution is inelegant.

Comment: Also modifiers of private methods can be changed, so that way we can test everything.

Comment: Yes, it is one of options, but what if test are in different package? If I have package with source code and package with test?

Comment: Usually in IDEs, we have 2 different folders. One is for source code, second for tests.

Comment: @Pawel: that's not usual, your IDE doesn't force this (at least eclipse, netbeans, IDEA don't). you should have separate folders for src and tests, maven-style, above the package level.

Comment: IDE does not force, but it good practise to have separate folders. I have separate folders (maven-style), but I cannot acces protected/package-private methods of src folder from test folder. How should it be organized?